# How concat two fields to return list LINQ then get with javascript

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method like this:

```
public ActionResult GetUsuario()
{
    var listaUsuarios = db.Usuarios.ToList();
    return Json(listaUsuarios, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

But now I only want list of objects containing the `Name` and `LastName` properties of the users.

How can I select them, concat these properties, and return it as a JsonList?

I want something like:

```
public ActionResult GetUsuario()
{
    var listaUsuarios = db.Usuarios.Select(x => x.Name + " " + x.LastName).ToList();
    return Json(listaUsuarios, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I return elements as I want, for example: Rene Mondo

[image]

The problem its an array I get it as [0] instead a database Object, so I have javascript like this:

```
$("#lstProveedor")
    .getJSONCatalog({
        onSuccess: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        url: '/Agenda/GetUsuario',
        valueProperty: "ID",
        textProperty: ""
    });
```

My question is: how can I get that return value as my textProperty?

Comment: Are you actually asking how to return objects with properties? Use an anonymous type.

Comment: Yes I want to return objects with properties

Comment: try something like this: "var listaUsuarios = db.Usuarios.Select(u => new { u.Name, u.LastName, FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", u.Name, u.LastName})).ToList();"

Comment: I try as you comment but I get issue: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code @user1304444

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to return an object with an `ID` property (as `valueProperty`) and a property that serves as `textProperty`

```
var listaUsuarios = db.Usuarios.Select(x => new
{
    ID = x.ID,
    FullName = x.Name + " " + x.LastName
}).ToList();
```

Then in the javascript:

```
$("#lstProveedor")
.getJSONCatalog({
    onSuccess: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    url: '/Agenda/GetUsuario',
    valueProperty: "ID",
    textProperty: "FullName"
});
```